# Insert or Update MySQL database if 3 fields match

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE `list` (
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `note` text,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and I would like to INSERT a new row into the database if a row with given *name*, *value* and *id* don't exist, otherwise I would like to update the note field. My insert query looks as follows:

```
INSERT INTO list (name, value, id, note) 
VALUES("test", 2, 221222, "this is a test")
```

I am not sure what to do, as I don't have a primary key in the list and haven't been able to figure out how to set unique fields. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What can be the maximum character lengths of `name` and `value` fields ? Why not just define them as `varchar` ? If these fields are varchar, then you can easily define a UNIQUE constraint, or even better would be PRIMARY key on the combination of `(name, value, id)`. Afterwards, you can employ [`IODKU`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Note: MyISAM is an obsolete database engine, try and use InnoDB, and `latin1` character columns also cause huge problems for pretty much everyone, `utf8mb4` is a safer default.

Comment: I have updated my name and value fields to varchar, set Primary, and IODKU works perfectly well now. Thank you!

Comment: `REPLACE INTO db (` with `VALUES (` ? I think this would allow you to not only add the values, but also permit you to *change* some of the values as suggested in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to insert a new row into the database if a row with given `name`, `value` and `id` don't exist.

**Option 1**

You can write a query that checks if the record already exists before inserting it:

```
INSERT INTO list (name, value, id, note) 
SELECT 'test', 2, 221222, 'this is a test'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM list 
    WHERE name = 'test' AND value = 2 AND id = 221222 AND note = 'this is a test'
);
```

The downside of this approach is that you need to specify the values to insert twice. The advantage is that it does not require you to alter the table strucutre, hence it won't have side effects on other potential queries.

**Option 2**

You can take advantage of MySQL `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax. First of all, you  would need to create a composiye unique constraint on all 3 columns:

```
ALTER TABLE list ADD UNIQUE list_unique_index(id, name, value);
```

This actually prevents duplicates from being inserted (by any mean). Then you can express the query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO list (name, value, id, note) 
    VALUES("test", 2, 221222, "this is a test")
    ON DUPLICATE KEYS UPDATE id = id
```

If the unique constraint validation fails, MySQL executes the `UPDATE id = id` clause, which is basically a no-op.

Note: there is a third option that consists in using `INSERT ... IGNORE`. I would not recommend that since that actually hides all error that could happen in the query (not only those related to the unique constraint); this behavior can bite you somehow.